# QProcess does not start

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

For some reason, I am unable to start a process using QProcess on Ubuntu, and I do not understand why...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Run the process:
    QString procName = "./path/to/executable/Individual";
    QProcess *proc = new QProcess();

    proc->start(procName);
    if(!proc->waitForStarted())
    {
        std::cout<<"Fail!"<<std::endl;
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    int exitCode = proc->exitCode();

    std::cout<<"Exit code: "<<exitCode<<std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

This always prints 'Fail' to the terminal.

If I type `./path/to/executable/Individual` into the terminal, it works just fine, so the path seems to be correct.

Can anyone tell me why the program will not start?

I am using Qt version 5.9.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: The problem is in the current working directory of your application. As you use a relative path, it cannot find your executable. Try to use the full path instead or start application from the correct location.

Comment: You should use [QFileInfo::exists()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#exists) to make sure `Individual` is accessible from your program

Comment: @vahancho: Nope, the path is absolute (starting with /home/[username]/

Comment: @Antwane: Just tried it, qFileInfo says that the file exists.

Comment: @DrDonut can you ensure it is executable using QFileInfo::isExecutable() ?

Comment: @Antwane: Yes, isExecutable() returns true.

Comment: Did you tried to launch another executable?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: If I put proc->start("/bin/bash"); it does not print 'Fail', but it does not open a terminal window either...

Comment: By default, waitForFinished() has a timeout of 30 seconds. Does your program print "Fail" immediatly, or after a few seconds ? 30 seconds ?

Comment: @Antwane: It prints it immediatly, for sure faster than 30 seconds.

Comment: @DrDonut Of course `bash` isn't a terminal emulator, it's just a shell. Anyway this means that you can launch something at that something's wrong with your executable... What `QProcess::errort()` reports?

Comment: What kind of executable is it? scrip? Binary?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: It is a compiled C++ program, it should return statuscode -1. The error code I get is 0, which means 'FailedToStart'

Comment: Is there any whitespace in the path? Or weird char? Could you please give us the path used, exactly as it is used?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: I think I figured it out... In the process assignment I used "./absolute/path/executable", as I understood it from the QProcess documentation. It seems I should have used "/absolute/path/executable". p-a-o-l-o's answer made me see that, by showing that the proc->start("individual") worked. Thank you all so much for your time and effort!

Comment: Of course, a path starting with a dot is not absolute but relative

Comment: @Antwane, Ah, so that's why you said my path was relative, sorry, I thought that just meant to execute the file, like what you do in your terminal. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using Linux, you can

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/executable/Individual /usr/local/bin/individual
```

then try:

```
proc->start("individual");
```

Comment: And typing `individual` in console starts the program?

Comment: Oops, capitalisation problem... Yes, it does seem to start and even finish now, although the exit code gives 255 where I expect -1, could that be a signed/unsigned problem?

Comment: Also, why does it work this way, and not from an absolute path?

Comment: Yes it was, I used the dot before the filename, as I understood it from the QProcess documentation, apperantly I should not have done that. Your answer made me see that. And yes, I figured out the return code 255 was a signed/unsigned problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
proc->start("cd /usr/local/bin/ && individual");
```